# B1/B2 in admin processing for 20 months and now I've moved to another country. Should I notify post, re-apply or do something else?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I am a Russian citizen and have applied for a B1/B2 visa at Moscow Consulate back in September 2013. After interview I've been given a 221(g) letter and my application was put under 'Administrative processing'. It is still in this status as of today.

During those two years since submitting the application a lot of my personal information has changed: I got married, changed job, and, perhaps most important in the context of the question, moved to Czech Republic, where I have employment-based long-term residency.

My question is what's the proper course of action in such scenario? Should I notify Moscow consulate of those changes (and how)? Should I request my case to be transferred to Prague consulate (are there any pros or cons of doing that)? Should I recall my application and submit it again in Prague?

2 years of admin processing for B1/B2 isn't something you see every day (or is it?) so I'm a bit lost here. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed a highly unusual case. Most visa applications sent in for administrative processing are completed within 60 days, and the State Department says you should inquire with the consulate if more than 60 days has passed.

If your application is still showing in administrative processing in [CEAC](https://ceac.state.gov/CEACStatTracker/Status.aspx?eQs=WwjqOlbeRYzCYubaSQI%20RA==), then I would first contact the consular section in Moscow to ask them why your application has taken more than a year and a half to process. I would not bother emailing the address given on the embassy web site as that is answered by the third party that accepts visa applications. I would call the consular section directly on +7 (495) 745 33 88.

If you can't get a straight answer out of the consular section, [an immigration lawyer](http://lawandborder.com/administrative-processing-black-hole-visa-applicants/) recommends your next step be to contact the State Department Visa Office. [They can be reached](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/contact.html) on +1 (603) 334-0888.

After that, if you still get nowhere you will probably need help from an immigration lawyer or a member of the US Congress.

Comment: Michael, thank you! I am checking in with consulate regularly but they do not provide any useful information (beyond what's seen via CEAC tracking). I did talk to Visa Office about a year ago and it's probably about time to try them again :) Any thought on should I ask for my case to be transferred to Prague and/or notify Moscow post of change of country?

Comment: I can't say. My first thought would be that it would just complicate the case even further. At this point I would be hesitant to do anything else without an immigration lawyer.

Comment: @Andrey 221(g) is basically a refusal http://visarefusal.com/221g/ and http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/general/ineligibilities.html  Long story short you are for some reason may have been considered ineligible: http://www.uscis.gov/iframe/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-29/0-0-0-2006.html

Comment: Karlson, you are absolutely incorrect. Administrative processing with 221(g) in the vast majority of cases (>95% for sure) results in the issued visa. Moreover this processing is mandatory for some people based solely on their education or workplace.

Comment: @mts, [Look here for 221(g) refusals.](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Statistics/AnnualReports/FY2015AnnualReport/FY15AnnualReport-TableXX.pdf) It isn't 95%, but in 2015 it was 85% for non-immigrant visas and 65% for immigrant visas. Of course a 221(g) does mean you need to forever answer "yes" to "refused a visa" questions irrespective of the eventual outcome.

Comment: @mts, P.S. he's also correct that having certain skills or occupations will result in the need for a [Visas Mantis SAO](https://www.nafsa.org/findresources/Default.aspx?id=8645), and a 221(g) to allow for that. I don't know what fraction of applications this is since they are opaque about the reason for Administrative Processing for anything beyond missing documents.