# F1 Visa approved but passport given back without stamping

Tags: visas, f1-visas

I have attended F1 visa interview on 23rd Nov 2016 and the interview was good.

Visa Officer verified my i20, GRE, TOEFL and Financial docs(Loan sanction letter + Parent's bank balance certificates).

After verifying them, she gave them back **Kept DS160 confirmation form and loan sanction letter with her**

and said

"*Taking into consideration that all you have said is true, I'm granting your visa. Please come back for getting your passport stamped.*"

Then she gave back my passport (which should not be the case in granting visa) and also handovered me white 221g slip with case number and I left the counter.

She said I will be informed via mail when to go to Consulate again for stamping.

Is my visa granted or rejected ?

As my date of orientation is close and I need to make arrangements of my travel, I need visa asap. Will this process take much time for completion ?

The status of my visa is  *Administrative Processing*

Comment: Which part of "I'm granting your visa" did you not understand?

Comment: they gave back my passport, that should not be the case is visa is granted ryt

Comment: Is there any particular reason you dont believe you will be called back to have it stamped, as per "She said I will be informed via mail when to go to Consulate again for stamping"? They gave you back your passport because they no longer need it, but you might need it.

Comment: In case if visa is approved, they will keep passport with themselves and call us once stamping is done. My case is not so.. I have searched online and seen many others like me who were not called back and after so many days they responded to emails and then process started again

Comment: Can you add your country where you were applying from ?

Answer (score 3):

The good news is that they found no reason not to grant your visa, so you can expect that you will ultimately get it. The bad news is that it has gone into administrative processing, so you will need to wait a while to get it. The [official guidance](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/administrative-processing-information.html) is that most cases will be resolved within 60 days of the interview, and that you shouldn't make inquiries about it until that amount of time has passed.

The State Department has never said what administrative processing is, but Internet rumors (for what that's worth) tend to suggest that it involves a request to other agencies, made after they have your biometrics and sworn statements from the interview, to see if they have derogatory information about you that the State Department was unaware of. If there is no such information to be had you are good. Note that this is "normal", in that a certain fraction of all visa applications end up in administrative processing, and I have personally not heard of a case where the person in administrative processing did not ultimately get their visa. The State Department has also never said what triggers administrative processing. It might even be random or algorithmic selection having little to do with you personally.

In any case, you can expect to get your visa but you have no choice but to wait out the administrative processing delay, and you'll need to deal with any consequences of that since there is no way to hurry them up. Chalk it up to bad luck.

Comment: [Now you have.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49702/3221)